# Which one is better among skipping Indexes or drop&rebuild indexes?

Tags: oracle11g

Can you please let me know which approach is better among skipping Indexes or dropping & rebuilding indexes  for large amount of data .

Thanks
Sreenivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load a large volume of data you need to disable/drop all your indexes, except primary key, you might want to keep (do not disable/drop them) unique indexes if you have any. Then you need to perform loading and then rebuild/create indexes you disabled/dropped. It saves you some time.